# Regex to match nested class Java

Tags: java, c++, regex, boost

I am trying to use boost regex that looks at some Java source to identify its "main" class. (Edit: Note I am not trying parse the entire file. Just looking for a specific pattern within the file). I am stuck trying to parse nested classes properly. The best I have is this:

```
static const regex PUBLIC_STATIC_MAIN_STR(
     "class\\s+(\\w+)((?!class).)*public\\s+static\\s+void\\s+main\\s*?\\(");
```

For e.g. in this example the answer is InnerClass, which I am able to correctly parse:

```
class OuterClass {
    ... 
    class InnerClass {
        ...
        public static void main () {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But in this case it fails. The following should return OuterClass:

```
class OuterClass {
     ... 
     class InnerClass {
         ...
     }

     public static void main () {
         ...
     }
 }
```

Ofcourse the challenge is to deal with the recrusion. You can say it is an error if there are more than one class with a public static void main.

Can someone help?

Comment: Java isn't a regular language. Don't try to parse it with regexes, because that doesn't work, by definition.

Comment: As Larry Wall said: "'Regular expressions' [...] are only marginally related to real regular expressions. Nevertheless, the term has grown with the capabilities of our pattern matching engines, so I'm not going to try to fight linguistic necessity here. I will, however, generally call them "regexes" (or "regexen", when I'm in an Anglo-Saxon mood)" Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Modern Regular Expressions can match languages that are not even Context Free!